# Moderate first forum post only

Tags: forum

I'm looking to require the first forum post of a member to be moderated before it goes live but then allow all subsequent posts to post automatically.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

"You can moderate *who* is allowed to post, but not the posts themselves."
http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/219793/#1013472

I'm not sure, but maybe you can create a post-only forum (for the "new-member" group) and once approved move the message to the regular forums and assign the user to "regular-members" group.